# Get the lastest tweet of multiple users in a single request

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Is there any way I can get the latest tweet/status update of multiple Twitter-friends in a single request
An API call for the same would look as below

`latestStatus = getLatestStatus(new long[]{userId1, userId2, userId3});`

So as I pass in the input array of user id's (or screennames), I get the latest status update (or the status id) as an output.

I can do this one request per user, but then it exceeds the Rate Limit.

Language no barrier, even an HTTP Get request algorithm is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Twitter4j.

You can use the lookupUsers(long[]) method.  This will return information (including latest status) from up to 100 users at once.  Check out: [http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html#lookupUsers(long[])](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html#lookupUsers%28long%5B%5D%29) for more details.

example:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
ResponseList<User> userInfo = twitter.lookupUsers(new long[]{userId1, userId2, userId3});
for(User u: userInfo){
  System.out.println(u.getScreenName() + ": " + u.getStatus().getText());
}
```